# How to check if API session is valid when no API calls on that page

Tags: node.js, api, express, session, passport.js

### Problem

I am creating a backend API using express and passport.

On the frontend, I want to send the user to login screen if session is invalid but some pages don't make any API calls.

How can I do this?

### What I Normally Do

Normally I have an API call like `/userinfo` that I call on all pages when the application loads, mostly to check if session is valid. Then I set a flag to avoid checking session again.

I don't like having to make that API call just to check session.

### Ideas

I thought of checking for the existence of cookie `connect.sid` and making sure it's deleted on `/logout`.

This is annoying to manage in development because the cookie might not be accessible by front-end webserver (backend and frontend on different ports).

Comment: is it a single page application (react or angular) in frontend  side ??

Comment: Yes this is an Angular front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach I suggest is make an api call in your top most main component to check wether the session is valid or not (meanwhile u can show a loader to user). If the api call was successfull store the session info in your state. So when every other component loads check wether the user is loggedin or not by checking in session info. If not redirect to login page.